# How to tell if the Pi Camera is connected?

Tags: raspicam, picamera

Simple question, but searching did not return an answer.

I have a Pi4 and a Pi Camera.  This camera is not USB and does not appear in `lsusb` output when it is working.

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

What command to give to show if the camera is connected correctly?

Comment: What OS? What Pi? What have YOU done to set it up?

Comment: @Milliways My question is trying to be generic.   In MY case I found I must have tugged the cable and partially pulled it from the onboard socket.   However the question remains, mostly to assist future searchers in solving their problem.

Comment: In which case the Question is useless - indeed worse than useless, it is misleading due to the changed camera stack in Bullseye which most users will have.

Comment: @Milliways feel free to answer and/or downvote, or flag as appropriate then.   Or if the answer exists in another question, flag as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely at this point in time you will need to run `libcamera-hello` to see if the camera is working.

Docs: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html

Most examples are going to have you open `sudo raspi-config` and enable the legacy camera features. That's a good option if you are a beginner. However, there are a lot of ways to record images and videos with your pi/camera.

Comment: This host is running octoprint, and libcamera-hello is not installed.  I'm specifically looking for command to show if the pi camera is connected/detected

Comment: ...had to install `libcamera-apps` to get this.   Looks like its not Picamera specific either, mine finds a USB-connected camera at /dev/video0 which is correct.

Answer (score 3):

From command line, you could use `vcgencmd` utility as shown below:

```
$ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1, libcamera interfaces=0
```

When no camera detected the output would be:

```
$ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=0 detected=0
```

Comment: Nice - thank you.  I get "supported=1 detected=1" but not the interfaces part after the comma.

Comment: the output differs due to Raspbian OS release. libcamera one is a new addition in Bullseye. BTW, you could also use Python package (`pip install vcgencmd`).

Answer (score 1):

There is **nothing** in `dmesg` to show whether the camera was detected or not.

---

Not connected/detected:

```
# raspistill -o output.jpg
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly
```

---

Connected OK:

```
# raspistill -o output.jpg

# echo $?
0

# ll output.jpg 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1672456 Apr 10 12:40 output.jpg
```

And there's a jpeg file created which is a valid snap from the picam.